# react native navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I'm developing an app where I need to know user's current location. For now, I'm using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, but it's not convenient. It doesn't always get the current location, again it doesn't work on all devices with same parameters. 
So, I want to know is there any other library which is more convenient or anything I can do in the current method which will get the current location without failing?
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The React Native geolocation stuff polyfills the [HTTP API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) which is stable and works the same across all platforms.

Have you tried getting location on an actual device?

- iOS simulator caches the location heavily, and doesn't refresh until you restart simulator.
- Android emulator is a little more lax. But with either, you need to hardcode location coordinates.

Only your web browser or an actual device will give you accurate results every time.

Comment: yes, i've tried in actual devices, but it doesn't work well in all devices